How to pass custom data into Email Provider Next Auth
I am using Next Auth v5. I want to pass in the user's timezone on login so that I can have the timezone in SSR pages that are timezone sensitive. I can't figure out how to pass custom data into NextAuth.
I have my own sign in page where I call the signIn function. I have tried passing in the timezone there as well as appending it to my callback url. The problem is I can't figure out how to access it in my jwt nor session callbacks.
Is this even possible to do? If not, what would be a better way to get the client's timezone into the session.
Thanks.

Possible
In your callbacks, you're going to pass a new prop called tz
async jwt({ token, user, account, trigger, session }) {
    if (account && user) {
        // other assignments...
        token.tz = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
    }
    
    return token
},
async session({ session, token }) {
    return {
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            // other assignments...
            tz: token.tz as any,
        },
        error: token.error,
    }
}

To be able to use our own session props, we need to add type folder at the root level of the project and put next-auth.d.ts file inside it
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        id: string
        tz: any
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}

Now we can access tz prop in a Server Component just like that
import { auth } from "auth" // comes from auth.ts file

const ServerComponentInWhichWeNeedSessionData = () => {
    const session = await auth()
    console.log("session (server side)", session)
    const tz = session?.tz
    console.log("tz", tz)

    return <h1>ServerComponentInWhichWeNeedSessionData</h1>
}


Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that won't work because the timezone offset is being generated on the server where the jwt callback is happening. I need to know the client's timezone. I would like to be able to pass it in from the client on sign in/sign up.
